# Which format to choose to convert to ShapeFiles?

Tags: shapefile, kml, convert, csv, ogr2ogr

Given the following format options:

[all.json](http://www.berlin.de/ba-charlottenburg-wilmersdorf/org/umwelt/natur/baeume/index.php/index/all.json?q=),
[all.xml](http://www.berlin.de/ba-charlottenburg-wilmersdorf/org/umwelt/natur/baeume/index.php/index/all.xml?q=),
[all.xls](http://www.berlin.de/ba-charlottenburg-wilmersdorf/org/umwelt/natur/baeume/index.php/index/all.xls?q=),
[all.csv](http://www.berlin.de/ba-charlottenburg-wilmersdorf/org/umwelt/natur/baeume/index.php/index/all.csv?q=),
[all.kml](http://www.berlin.de/ba-charlottenburg-wilmersdorf/org/umwelt/natur/baeume/index.php/index/all.kml?q=),
[all.gjson](http://www.berlin.de/ba-charlottenburg-wilmersdorf/org/umwelt/natur/baeume/index.php/index/all.gjson?q=)

Which one is the best/easiest to convert the data into standard ERSI Shapefiles which contains the coordinates as well as the data attributes for each feature?

I tried importing KML and JSON via [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org) but the data attributes are squashed into a single column (see screenshot). Conversion via [ogr2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) was successful neither - it spits out a DBF file only. Conversion via [csv2shp](https://code.google.com/p/csv2shp/) did not work at all - I could not figure out how to run the command.

[image: QGIS Attributes Table]

---

I came up with the following `all.vrt` as [suggested by afalciano](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/84769/which-format-to-choose-to-convert-to-shapefiles/84772?noredirect=1#comment117404_84772).

```
<OGRVRTDataSource>
    <OGRVRTLayer name="all">
        <SrcDataSource>all.csv</SrcDataSource>
        <GeometryType>wkbPoint</GeometryType>
        <LayerSRS>WGS84</LayerSRS>
        <GeometryField encoding="PointFromColumns" x="laengengrad" y="breitengrad"/>
    </OGRVRTLayer>
</OGRVRTDataSource>
```

All features are printed to the console running: `ogrinfo -ro -al all.vrt`

Comment: It sounds like you are saying that four of the six are not working (well) for you and implied that you have not tried the other two.  I think you should decide which is your preferred format and focus your Question on how to get that converted satisfactorily.  If that works then getting the others working becomes more or less moot, or can be researched/asked separately.  Dealing with six workflows in one Question is not going to align well with our Q&A format.  Whereas one Question per workflow will likely yield a clean and valuable Q&A about each.

Comment: The point is that I have no idea which source format and conversion tool allows to separate the data columns as desired for the ShapeFiles. That is why I do not decide on a format to work with.

Comment: CSV format is more human readable than others and QGIS treats it very fine. IMHO the choice is very simple here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily add `all.csv` using semicolon as custom delimiter, `laengengrad` field as `X` and `breitengrad` one as `Y`. Finally save as SHP and you're done.

[image]

Sorry for the Italian ui.

Comment: Awesome! I tried this before but missed to change the column separator to semicolon. Sometimes it is that easy! Can you tell how to the same via ogr2ogr?

Comment: You should use the `OGR VRT` format in order to manage delimiters and geometry fields. I suggest to read this [doc](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_csv.html). Hope this helps.

Comment: Odd thing about the data is that Northing and Easting data has decimal comma and thousand points, while Laengengrad and Breitengrad has decimal point.

Comment: @afalciano Does the `.vrt` file help me with the conversion? Still `ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" all.shp all.csv` outputs the `.dbf` only.

Comment: It should be `ogr2ogr all.shp all.vrt` using the `all.vrt` you added in your question. OGR recognizes the separator automatically (if possible), so you don't need to declare it.

Comment: @afalciano Great. I did not know this command. - I noticed that the `.dbf` produced by this command is have the size compared to the ShapeFiles export from QGIS after importing the `.csv` as described by you before. Though, I cannot find a contentual difference.

Answer (score 0):

Ansuming that XML stands for GML, that's the way I would go. I regularly use QGis to convert from ShapeFile to GML and vice-versa. The only issue that sometimes arises is wrong attribute types.